# Set the maximum date to today in ngx-bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am very beginner in Angular.

I have problem with my ....

I have this code:

```
  onDateSelection(date: NgbDate, datepicker: any) {
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && date) {
      this.toDate = date;
      datepicker.close();
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }


<div class="col-9 col-md-8">
      <div class="dp-hidden position-absolute kalendarz">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input
            name="datepicker"
            class="form-control"
            ngbDatepicker
            #datepicker="ngbDatepicker"
            [autoClose]="'outside'"
            (dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event, datepicker)"
            [displayMonths]="2"
            [dayTemplate]="t"
            outsideDays="hidden"
            [startDate]="fromDate!"
            tabindex="-1"
          />
          <ng-template #t let-date let-focused="focused">
                    <span
            class="custom-day"
            [class.focused]="focused"
            [class.range]="isRange(date)"
            [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
            (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
            (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null"
          >
                        {{ date.day }}
                    </span>
          </ng-template>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input
          #dpFromDate
          readonly
          class="form-control dpFromDate"
          placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
          name="dpFromDate"
          id="dpFromDate"
          [value]="formatter.format(fromDate) + ' - ' + formatter.format(toDate)"
          (input)="fromDate = validateInput(fromDate, dpFromDate.value)"
        />
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi bi-calendar3" (click)="datepicker.toggle()" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It's work fine.

Currently it works so that I can select a date range (date from and date to). The FROM date and the TO date can be the same day. This is ok.

I would like my FROM date to be TODAY or any earlier date. So if today is 06/06/2023 - then the FROM date would be 06/06/2023, 01/06/2023, 01/01/2022 - but it cannot be 07/06/2023.

We can anyone how to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import { NgbDate } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

// ...

onDateSelection(date: NgbDate, datepicker: any) {
  const selectedDate = new Date(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);

  if (selectedDate.getTime() <= Date.now()) {
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && date) {
      this.toDate = date;
      datepicker.close();
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }
}
```

This way you ensure that the **FROM date** is always set to **today's date** or an **earlier** date